# how can print multidimensional arrays values in jsp?

Tags: php, arrays, jsp

In PHP Page, to print array, I use print_r();
In jsp, to print string, out.print() is used.
for example :

> `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>`

was is equal in jsp???
How can I print array values in jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 System.out.println( mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(myList) );
```

myList is your array varible .

or for post data try

```
Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();
for(String parameter : parameters.keySet()) {
    if(parameter.toLowerCase().startsWith("your object name in html")) {
        String[] values = parameters.get(parameter);
        //your code here
    }
}
```

and ***import java.util.Map***

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop

```
String[] colors = {"red", "green", "blue"};
   for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      out.print("<P>" + colors[i] + "</p>");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to something like this :

```
<%
    out.println(StringUtils.join(variable,"<br />");
%>
```

If you actually want to print POST variables, follow this link :

[Get all parameters from JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548687/get-all-parameters-from-jsp-page)

Answer (score 0):

@todayslate gave a good answer, only that you have to know the length of the array for that. Now, of course that you can just check the length (by `colors.length`), but I find it more appealing to do:

```
String[] colors = {"red", "green", "blue"};
//suppose you have no idea how many colors are in the 
//array since you received it from another method or something
for (String color: colors) {
     out.print("<P>" + color + "</p>");
}
```