# how to get the value of name field of submit button which i can view on page source?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have created one HTML form which consists of multiple buttons of `"edit"` and `"delete"`. I put them in a `for` loop in order to view many of them on another page.

How can I get the name field of the submit button, or whichever button I have clicked, on the next JSP page? Or, can you can provide me an alternative for this?

```html
<% for (int t = 1; t < 10; t++) { %>
    <label>
        <input type="submit" name="<%=t %>" value="edit" onclick="this.form.action='df1.jsp?flag=1&act=1';this.form.submit();" />
        <input type="submit" name="<%=t %>" value="delete" onclick="this.form.action='df1.jsp?flag=1&act=1';this.form.submit();" />
    </label>
<% } %>
```

When I view the page source, it's showing the `name="1"` for edit and `name="1"` for delete till `10`.

I want to get the value of name field on server side. I also can't apply `request.getParameter()`, because I am not aware which button will user hit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden tag, which stores the value of the clicked button

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidBt" />
```

Place this hidden tag outside the value.

```
<label>
    <input type="submit" name="<%=t %>" value="edit" onclick="this.form.hidBt.value=this.value;this.form.action='df1.jsp?flag=1&act=1';this.form.submit();" />
    <input type="submit" name="<%=t %>" value="delete" onclick="this.form.hidBt.value=this.value;this.form.action='df1.jsp?flag=1&act=1';this.form.submit();" />
</label>
```

After that call the hidden variable

```
String butValue = request.getParameter("hidBt");
```

Comment: this hidden tag is displaying the name of button  i.e edit or delete

Comment: @user1950705: Yes, thats what you are looking for. The submit button values are **edit** and **delete**.

Comment: i m not looking for edit or delete.........i want to get the value of  name field i.e "1" for edit and "1" for delete

Comment: i am looking for the name value i e"1" for edit and "1" delete......which in can see on page src

Answer (score 0):

As you're already changing the form action URL in the onclick (which is a very poor practice, but that aside), why not just adding the row identifier along as well?

```
<input type="submit" name="<%=t %>" value="edit" onclick="this.form.action='df1.jsp?flag=1&act=1&edit=<%=t%>';this.form.submit();" />
<input type="submit" name="<%=t %>" value="delete" onclick="this.form.action='df1.jsp?flag=1&act=1&delete=<%=t%>';this.form.submit();" />
```

This way you can just do:

```
String edit = request.getParameter("edit");

if (edit != null) {
    // Edit button of row "edit" was invoked. Do your job here.
}

String delete = request.getParameter("delete");

if (delete != null) {
    // Delete button of row "delete" was invoked. Do your job here.
}
```

Otherwise you'd need to prefix the button name with some fixed identifier:

```
<input type="submit" name="edit_<%=t %>" value="edit" onclick="this.form.action='df1.jsp?flag=1&act=1';this.form.submit();" />
<input type="submit" name="delete_<%=t %>" value="delete" onclick="this.form.action='df1.jsp?flag=1&act=1';this.form.submit();" />
```

So that you can just do:

```
for (int t = 1; t < 10; t++) {
    if (request.getParameter("edit_" + t) != null) {
        // Edit button on index "t" was invoked. Do your job here.
        break;
    }

    if (request.getParameter("delete_" + t) != null) {
        // Delete button on index "t" was invoked. Do your job here.
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, writing JSPs this way with *scriptlets* `<% %>` is since a decade considered oldschool and a poor practice. See also [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches you could take to this.

## Look at all the submitted fields

- Get all the fields that were submitted (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548687/get-all-parameters-from-jsp-page))
- Loop over them
- Pattern match their names until you find one that matches the naming convention you have for your submit buttons

## Look for all possible submit button names

- Generate a list of all the submit button names you could have
- Loop over that list attempting to get a parameter with each name until you find one

---

Given your names are numeric, the number of possibilities is possibly not finite. So the first approach is probably better.

Answer (score -1):

```
you can get button using 

String buttonName =  request.getParameter("button-name")
```

Then you have to pass the value as hidden value to next page;

Comment: wanna to get submit button value

Comment: i am looking for the name value i e"1" for edit and "1" delete......which in can see on page src